# Run a simple C program with Sublime Text 2 in external terminal on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, build, terminal, sublimetext2

first steps with building and running C/Cpp with Sublime Text on Ubuntu. I read here and there and I came up with this following working sublime-build:

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++, source.cxx, source.cpp",
    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell": true,
            "cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}; exec bash\"'"]
        }
    ]    
}
```

Are there better approaches especially at keeping the terminal open after execution is completed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: Seems what you have does work as is. Is there a reason you're looking for a "better" approach? What do you not like about what you're doing now?

Answer (score 1):

It works on Ubuntu 14.04

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++, source.cxx, source.cpp",
    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell": true,
            "cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"${file_path}/${file_base_name};echo;echo;  echo Press ENTER to continue; read line;exit; exec bash\"'"]
        }
    ]    
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain how it works? I want to learn from that.

Comment: And, do you know how to **build and run**? I don't want to build once and run once every time I debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try chaning from

```
"cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}; exec bash\"'"]
```

to

```
"cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}; echo 'Press ENTER to continue'; read line; exec bash\"'"]
```