# Error with scanf() by compiling a C program in Sublime Text 2

Tags: c, sublimetext2

I finally managed to configure the compiler for `C` in Sublime Text 2. In a `int main()` function, there is no problem with `printf()`, but there is a problem with the compiler using `scanf()`. It does not allow keyboard input and jump instruction.

There is the build code for C:

```
{
    "cmd": ["gcc", "-Wall", "-ansi", "-pedantic-errors", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "selector": "source.c",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_path"
}
```

There is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int num, cube;

    printf("Enter a number for know the cube: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    cube = num * num * num;

    printf("\nThe cube %d is %d.\n\n", num, cube);

    return 0;
}
```

Screenshot below:

[image: error in scanf()]

[error in scanf()](http://sia1.subirimagenes.net/img/2015/01/16/150116021527262835.png)

[c build](http://sia1.subirimagenes.net/img/2015/01/16/150116022218603635.png)

Comment: Is it me, or it's impossible to know what the question is?

Comment: @iharob I'm sorry, but what I'm trying to explain is that the compiler does not expect to enter text from the keyboard, it will jump instruction and terminates execution.

Comment: @CésarNontol that doesn't make any sense at all, compilers don't expect text from keyboard to be entered, they compile programs.

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847916/run-a-simple-c-program-with-sublime-text-2-in-external-terminal-on-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: Posting your code rather than a screen shot is more useful.

Comment: A classic example of why it is important ot check the results of input functions like `scanf()`.  Bet it returns `EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sent input to your program via the Sublime Text console. You can just see the output of build systems or commands ran by python.
The build system is intend to run programs such as compilers that do not need to interact with the user.

I recommend to remove the call to execute your `.exe`, meaning remove `"&&", "${file_base_name}.exe"` and run your program in the windows console. There it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can't fix sublime, you can adjust your C.sublime-build file to have it open a terminal window and run the program.

Here's my adjustment that launches a new terminal window so you can properly use sublime as a full IDE for simple C development.

```
{
    "cmd": ["gcc", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "gcc '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && open -a Terminal '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm sure there are better ways to launch the terminal window, but it works.  If anyone has suggestions for improvements feel free to comment and I will adjust.